# ExpressJs no response from route when using child_process.exec

Tags: javascript, batch-file, express, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to execute a batch file when I hit a route in express, but for some reason I'm not getting a response.

```
app.get('/testRunBatch',  (req, res) => {
    exec('test.bat', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (!err) { return res.send("Batch Ran!");  }
        return res.send(err)
    });
});
```

However, the batch file runs successfully and in my case, creates an empty txt file.  What am I missing here?  Shouldn't the res.send() send a response back as soon as the callback for the exec is called?

Comment: Show some code.

Comment: updated, just threw some code in there.

Comment: I don't understand exactly what the problem is.  You say that your batch file does get run.  So, what exactly is the problem?  What do you observe?  What do you expect to happen that is not happening?

Comment: My route never sends a response so the server just hangs.

Comment: If you put a `console.log("in exec() callback")` does it get called?  If you put a `console.log("in testRunBatch route")`, does it get called?  You need to do some basic debugging here to help yourself out.

Comment: How are you calling this route?  By any chance, is it from an ajax call from client-side Javascript?  If so, nothing will show in the browser from an ajax call.  You have to get the response from your own client-side Javascript and then decide what to do with the response.